# why is my SVG element not following its path correctly?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I made a web design using Illustrator, copied it to Figma, and exported it as SVG.

I wanted the paper plane (#moveplane) to move along the dashed line so I drew a line, same shape as the dashed line, imported it as SVG, and copied the path for the plane to follow. But the plane strays away from the line, it's either too far along right or is completely far off.

I was wondering what could be the problem?

To give you a better idea, this is my Codepen - https://codepen.io/gelaciojica/pen/MWydLNm

```
#moveplane{
  motion-path: path("M264 105.5C313.833 82.5 425.8 39.1 475 49.5C496.013 53.9418 517.669 64.5128 535 79.5575M535 79.5575C568.392 108.544 585.733 154.139 551.5 204.5C491.5 253.5 345 126.615 535 79.5575ZM535 79.5575C607.333 63.3716 742 71 792.5 184.5C821.5 275 786 286.5 792.5 325C796.5 377.5 822.9 412.7 840.5 421.5");

  offset-path: path("M0.5 70.5C50.3333 47.5 133 -7.50001 242 1.58255C263.403 3.36603 284.669 16.5954 302 31.64M302 31.64C335.392 60.6268 352.733 106.221 318.5 156.583C258.5 205.583 112 78.6975 302 31.64ZM302 31.64C374.333 15.4542 509 23.0826 559.5 136.583C588.5 227.083 553 238.583 559.5 277.083C563.5 329.583 589.9 364.783 607.5 373.583");
  
  animation: move 4s linear ;
   
}
@keyframes move {
  100% { 
    motion-offset: 100%;
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
}
```

and that is the only part I edited in the SVG file.

Comment: Is it possible to simplify it a bit and remove the images and SVGs that aren't part of the problem?

Comment: It is, the problem is already in the snippet I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I would sugest to use `<animateMotion>` instead.

Also yoy can draw the plain as an svg group of elements or a symbol. I wouldn't use an image.

In order to debug the code make visible the path to be followed by the plain.

Also make sure the center of the plain is in the point x:0,y:0. In order to do this I've applied a transformation to the image.

```css
body{background:black}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1080 720" fill="none">

  <path id="path" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" d="M264 105.5C313.833 82.5 425.8 39.1 475 49.5C496.013 53.9418 517.669 64.5128 535 79.5575M535 79.5575C568.392 108.544 585.733 154.139 551.5 204.5C491.5 253.5 345 126.615 535 79.5575ZM535 79.5575C607.333 63.3716 742 71 792.5 184.5C821.5 275 786 286.5 792.5 325C796.5 377.5 822.9 412.7 840.5 421.5" />

  <image id="image0" width="256" height="256" x="-128" y="-128" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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">

    <animateMotion begin="0s" dur="10s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#path"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </image>
</svg>
```

Comment: The question was regarding CSS though. This is a pure SVG solution. Albeit, it appears to work.